# Detecting autofilled values on document ready

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, pageload, autofill

I have a login page on which I am trying to toggle the display of a button to allow the user to modify their roles (pick from a list of their user's available roles).

I am hiding the button initially and showing it on `$("#txtUsername").blur()`.

My question: is there a way to pick up a Chrome Autofilled value?

If I try to trigger it on document ready, the value is blank, and the button doesn't show.

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnRoles").hide();
    $("#txtUsername").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val()) $("#btnRoles").show();
        else $("#btnRoles").hide();
    }).trigger("blur");
});
```

But the textbox is then filled in via Autofill.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything to read the values specifically after the page had loaded.  I ended up forcing the focus on the textbox by using `$("#txtUsername").trigger("focus")`, so when the user did anything it would call `.blur()` and fill in the roles.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a security threat:

> Sadly as a security feature JavaScript is unable to access the autocomplete input data and instead returns a null string unless the submit button has been pressed (alert(document.loginform.user_logon.value) will not work).

[source](http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/10/clickjacking-and-xss-for-reading-autocomplete-credentials/)

Comment: But I can still check the values after the page is loaded using the console, even though they have been filled in by autocomplete.

Comment: Chrome console does not have some of the limitations that in-page scripts do.

Comment: this works after the page has loaded: `$(document).click(function () { alert($("#txtUsername").val()); })`

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... what if you just added an `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the `#txtUsername` input?